# The meaning of 取らせて in this sentence

Tags: meaning

The sentence is taken from a visual novel and it translates to

Did I take too much of your time ?

私が  余計に時間を取らせてしまったかしら

What I'm confused about is that the causative is "make someone do something/let someone do something"

So how does it work in this case ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

私が（キミに）余計に時間を取らせてしまったかしら <-- implicit object

Think about it as: "Did I make you take too much of your time?" which if you make it more English-like would translate to what you have above.